# Parse.View: event isn't working when I exit the view and enter it again

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm using Parse JS in version 1.3.4 in a web app project

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
```

in one of my Views, I have this declaration:

```
var DrivesView = Parse.View.extend({
  className :'backbone-container',
  options: {},
  events: {
      "click i.map-view-open-button": "openMapViewInModal"
   },
```

I wanted to put an event in a font awesome  element, which has the class `map-view-open-button`. `Parse` is somehow different than `Backbone` on this...

This works pretty well like this:

1. reload the page
2. go to the view (by clicking on the menu)
3. click on the `<i>` element --> my function `app.driveView.openMapViewInModal` runs ok
4. I can open the modal (run the function) several times, it works.

BUT, if I click on the menu and go to another view, and then come back to `app.driveView`, then the event won't work. The function `app.driveView.openMapViewInModal` won't be called if I click on the `<i>` element.

The strange parte is that the event is still there in the view. I checked it with `app.drivesView.events`.

Do I need to somehow close the view when I leave (how?) and then render it again so that the events will be recreated?

This is what I tried so far. I thought that I can delete the event on the render function, and create it again. The problem is that the render function will be called only once (at the first visit). If I leave the view and come back, the render function won't be called, which is really strange since my router points to this function (where `render` is explicitly called):

```
drivesViewer: function(){
    $('#app').html(this.driveView.render().el);
  },
```

any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It is really strange and against my expectation, but I'm not an expert, so my expectation is not really "valid".

here is what I did. On the viewer function I remove the view:

```
drivesViewer: function(){
    this.drivesView.remove();
    $('#app').html(this.driveView.render().el);
  },
```

Then, inside the 'DrivesView' declaration, I removed the 'events' attribute and put this lines in the 'render' function:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
this.delegateEvents({"click i.map-view-open-button": "openMapViewInModal"})
```

now, each time the view is loaded, I remove the view, then I undelegate the envents (not sure if really needed), then set new events. It works.

Note: I think there is a difference between Backbone and Parse here, don't really know why. Any comment and discussion on this is appreciated.